# python/py.test: writing assertion output into container

Tags: python, assert, pytest

I'm making some automated testing, in which I compare between two lists of data from two different sources.

I'm using assert in order to compare between strings, but I can't save the assert result.

Any suggestions? It could be using other method but I found assert as the most useful for now.

Thanks.

Comment: `assert` raises an exception if the _'asserted'_ statement is not true. It doesn't have any messages, does it?

Comment: Thats right, but if the condition is false I would like to write the statement down. Im less interested in cases of true conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
try:
    assert something==otherthing
except:
    f=open(log,"a")
    f.write("Assertion failed comparing something to otherthing\n")
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a message with the assertion using this method:

```
assert something == otherthing, "Assertion failed comparing {} to {}".format(something, otherthing)
```

When you do so, you should see the values appear where you used to see just a blank "AssertionError" message.

May I suggest using pytest as a basic for your automated tests. Assertions in pytest are reformatted to provide better introspection of the values making this extra step superfluous; take a look at [this pytest introduction](http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-introduction/), especially the "test_markdown" section where you can see how the asserts get some automatic introspection.